# Does the output of tf.nn.bias_add(value, bias) ever have a different shape than shape of value

Tags: tensorflow

So in the convolutional neural network cifar10 example in tensorflow, in the `inference()` method of cifar10.py I see several instances of this:

```
bias = tf.reshape(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases),conv.get_shape().as_list())
```

It seems like the reshape is making sure the output of `bias_add(value, bias)` has the shape of value

My question is, is the `tf.reshape()` necessary? Is there a situation where `tf.nn.bias_add(value, bias)` will not return a tensor with the same shape as value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [shape of the result](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py#L87) of `tf.nn.bias_add(value, bias)` is always the same as the shape of value, so these calls to `tf.reshape()` are unnecessary.

Occasionally, calls to `tf.reshape()` are used to add explicit information about the shape, but the [recommended way to do this, per the FAQ](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq#what_is_the_difference_between_xset_shape_and_x_tfreshapex), is to use the [`Tensor.set_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#set_shape) method to add shape information without adding a redundant operation to the graph.